# In JS, ES6, in a Factory, if the property and the param are different, then method is unable to find it

Tags: javascript

Javascript Beginner question:

In the following JS code - why cant the `radius` be found? :

```js
/* Constructor */

function createCircle(radiusVal, color){

    // returning an object
    return {
        radius:radiusVal,
        //In ES6, to simpilify syntax, the below code means color=color (param value).
        color,
        draw: function(){
            console.log('Area ::'+ Math.PI*radius*2);
            console.log ('Color ::'+ color);    
        }
    };

}

let cir1=createCircle(5,'yellow');
cir1.draw();
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: radius is not defined
    at Object.draw (factories_or_consts.js:12)
    at factories_or_consts.js:20
```

Comment: that parameter is `radiusVal`, not `radius`

Comment: Cause it's either `radiusVal` or `this.radius`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cant the `radius` be found?

It cannot be found because closure is not applicable here.

What is closure? - Closure is a concept in Javascript by which local variables & methods defined in a function are available to the child functions. In this case `radius` is a property of the `cir1` object & hence has to be accessed using the `this` keyword.

Research - https://youtu.be/PFmuCDHHpwk Location - 47:50 onwards

Answer (score 1):

Simple put `this` before the `radius` like `this.radius`. You're in a closure accessing the variable declared by the parent which is Object, it means outer. When you try to declare the `radius`, Interpreter will start lookin' for local, mean inner function "closure", and which doesn't exist. when you put `this`, it refers to parent Object:

```js
/* Constructor */

function createCircle(radiusVal, color){

    // returning an object
    return {
        radius:radiusVal,
        //In ES6, to simpilify syntax, the below code means color=color (param value).
        color,
        draw: function(){
            console.log('Area ::'+ Math.PI*this.radius*2);
            console.log ('Color ::'+ color);    
        }
    };

}

let cir1=createCircle(5,'yellow');
cir1.draw();
```

**Note**: Learn about [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8) keyword.

Comment: Isn't `this` unneeded? `radiusVal` has been closed over and doesn't change, so we could use that instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - why is this uneeded? What does this mean exactly - "radiusVal has been closed over and doesn't change". I am from the Java world, for me this is strange that draw() method, cannot access radius value, even though its within the same "class" body, so to speak.

Comment: @ArijitDatta on second look, I'm not correct. However, I would avoid `this` by using a closure (using the Module Revealing Pattern in this case).

Comment: @evolutionxbox - sorry you completely lost me. Would it be possible to give an example? What is the Module Revealing Pattern? My question still remains unanswered - why can't draw() access radius?

Comment: Using this answer can draw access radius?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - The answer provided by BloodyLogic works. That is, with the "this" keyword it works fine. Now I studied "closure" a bit more.  I understood, closure is not applicable here, because radius is defined on the cir1 object. Whereas closure refers to local variables defined parent function which are available to the child function.

Comment: I think it can apply, but it would be slightly more complicated. However, `this` works well here.